# Can anyone link to any paper regarding the circle method devised by Hardy & Ramanujan in finding approximations for the number of partitions?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

Can anyone link to any educational site or paper regarding the circle method devised by Hardy & Ramanujan in finding approximations for the number of partitions? Straightforward question, does anyone have like an introduction what this concept is, and so with a light-knowledge and grasp on this I can continue on knowing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An extension of the Hardy-Ramanuman circle method](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/Bringmann/Partition_sequences.pdf)

The reason I gave this reference instead of the Hardy-Ramanujan's original paper is because it contains the current state of the art in the cricle method. Also in the reference section of this paper you can find all the important references to the development of the method since Hardy and Ramanujan.